# Checking if an e-mail had already been added to a database

Tags: c#, asp.net

I am editing an ASP form that is basically a newsletter subscription form. The issue is that I have no way of triggering an event alerting me if a user has already registered.

I want to find a way to make the form check if that user's e-mail address exists within my database. If so, then just say, "You have already registered. Did you not receive a thank you email? Click here to receive the email again."

As it stands, the user can register and they automatically get the Thank you form, but are not necessarily told whether they've already registered or not.

EDIT: Sorry for not mentioning this earlier, but this database is managed using Microsoft's SQL Server. Yes, I am storing values using this method. Please let me know if I can include any more details -- I'm not very familiar with DBs.

Comment: how do you store the emails? mysql?

Comment: Yeah, you simply need to update the code that stores the email to test first and return a validation error instead. We need more details about how you're doing that to suggest how to help. (I might also drop the "Did you not receive a thank you email?" - it sounds a bit accusatory.)

Comment: run a query to determine if the email exist prior to doing anything if it exist then show the message if not then your additional logic

Answer (score 1, accepted):

in pseudo-code:

```
bool alreadyRegistered = (ReturnIntegerFromDatabase("select count(*) from table where email=\"emailAddress\"") > 0)
if(alreadyRegistered)
    alert();
else
    register();
```

I should also mention, since you are unfamiliar with databases, that you should always be wary of sql injection and take steps to prevent it.

Comment: Thanks for providing this answer. One thing that I wasn't sure of was how to write the actual query. This gave me a pretty good understanding of how to go about solving this issue. Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 1):

Well I am going to build on Isaac's approach. You still need to retrieve the email address if it already existed so you can send them an alert, this will save you another trip to the database. Consider the following method stubs:

```
public void EmailAlert(string email) {  }

public void Register(string email, ...) { }

public string FindEmail(string email) 
{ 
    //query
    SELECT *            
    FROM Table
    WHERE Email = 'passed in email'

    //pseudo code
    if (email exists)
    {
        return email address;
    }
    return null; 
 } //returns null if none found
```

Then your logic would look something like the following:

```
var email = FindEmail(givenEmail);
if (email != null)
{
    EmailAlert(email);
}
else
{
    Register(email, ...);
}
```

If you despise checking for null you can sub that piece in with whatever fits your style. This is really just to demonstrate the flow of logic, not the exact implementation details.

Comment: Thank you so much for provided a good introduction to the way that the flow logic is going to work. Although I chose another answer as my primary choice, your response has really helped me gain a  better understanding.

Answer (score 0):

Surely there's a backing store somewhere (database?) where registrations are saved; you can simply query it when they register and if you find it, act accordingly.

If you *don't* have a location where you store the email addresses (i.e., you just send the email as part of the process and then discard it) then you'll have to start saving them in order to facilitate the functionality you are describing.

Comment: I was thinking about this, but thought of whether or not there was a more efficient way of doing it.

Comment: Well I don't know how efficient or not it can be; if you're not saving the email addresses then there's no way for you to track them.

Comment: I definitely agree with this. I think that the best way to do this is to have a string be the base "query" and then write two modified versions of them with "insert into" and "if exists" to act accordingly.